# PCL: calculate the xyz for a point in mm

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I am using the kinect sensor and here is what I want to do. After I capture a IR frame and created a point map, I want to be able to calculate the X,Y and Z coordinates, of any point I want, from the kinect in millimeters (or any other real measurement).

For example: When I chose one random point from the cloud, it will tell me that it is 2000 mm in front, 100 mm on the left and 350 mm up. This way I can know the position of the point in the real word.

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: OpenNI grabber provided by PCL outputs points with coordinates in meters. Doesn't this suit your needs?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Point Cloud Library, and you seem to be, the point picking callback will allow you to build on PCLVisualizer to register a function to deal with a point (e.g. printing it out) when it is clicked:

http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.2.0/classpcl_1_1visualization_1_1_p_c_l_visualizer.html#ae8d38a6277cbab766b4e4c5e9c9b4e66

For more complex operations using the Point Cloud Library you probably need to get into VTK which is underneath the visualizer.